# Whats the best syntax for using html named anchor texts on tabs for better seo searchability?

Tags: seo, anchor

Question about **anchors in html**, with maximum seo-friendlyness as well as user-friendlyness. Currently, the tabs on our website use javascript-auto-created numeric  anchors e.g. when mouse hovering on them user sees: `page#1`, `page#2` and `page#3` Though this works fine, its not very sexy for a search engine, I guesse.

Now, tabs shows up in html as follows:

```
<div class="panel">
    <h3 class="tab">Tab Title</h3>
    <p>Contents</p>
</div>

<div class="panel">
    <h3 class="tab">Tab Title</h3>
    <p>Contents</p>
</div>
```

My plan is thus, to make non-auto, manually prescribed anchors on those javascript tab-buttons e.g. `page#overview`, `page#services`and `page#prices`.

**Q1. Would the new tab anchors make my site better searchable?**

**Q2. OR, should the anchor texts be more specific?**  if so, Why doesn't dreamweaver allow me to make bit more specific anchors e.g.
`page#architectural services overview` or
`page#ornamental garden fountains`?

When in Dreamweaver I navigate to `menu > Insert > Named Anchor` and fill in the single field something like "fountains". Then, Dreamweaver inserts the following:

```
<a name="fountains" id="fountains"></a>
```

**Q3. Are both neccessary** or is just one of part essential, or should that a tag be even broadened by adding a title="fountain" in other words, whats the best way to write elegant anchors these days?

**Q4. What are differences**, if any, between anchor, anchor-tag, named-anchor, html-anchor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's spiders don't render the page, as far as I can tell, as that would be pretty expensive to accomplish. They just look at the HTML. When you view the source of your site, it shows none of that JavaScript-generated content, and this is all Google (and any other engine) sees.

**Q1**: `page#overview` is specifying the ID of the element. `page#overview` is also invalid HTML, as there is no `<page>` element. Google reads what's *written* on the tabs, not their IDs. Just make them descriptive.

**Q2**: `page#architectural services overview` is completely invalid HTML. If you must make such a long ID, use underscores: `page#architectural_services_overview`. Otherwise, you might get some crazy results when rendering the page...

**Q3**: HTML attributes (`href`, `rel`, `alt`, `id`, `name`, `title`, etc.) each have a purpose. As you know, `href` is used to denote the location that a link points to. `name` is used by serverside scripts when you submit forms, so be nice to them. I would not touch the `name` unless it's being used by a PHP script or the alike.

**Q4**: This is why I don't like Dreamweaver... Anchors (correct me if I'm wrong) are used by the browser to scroll to elements within a page. They are denoted by the `id` of an element prepended with a `#`. Try [clicking here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911438/whats-the-best-syntax-for-using-html-named-anchor-texts-on-tabs-for-better-seo-se#top). The `href` is `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911438/whats-the-best-syntax-for-using-html-named-anchor-texts-on-tabs-for-better-seo-se#top`, and `#top` is the top of the document.

Similarly, clicking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911438/whats-the-best-syntax-for-using-html-named-anchor-texts-on-tabs-for-better-seo-se#footer-menu) brings you to the bottom. It references `#footer-menu`.

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

- JavaScript is done *browser-side*, so this won't have any SEO benefit (use 'fetch as googlebot' inside Google Webmaster Tools to verify what is actually be "indexed").
- Search engines ignore "fragments" (as the anchors are referred to when included in a URL). So, again, no SEO benefit.